# Viewing other user profile

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want users click on other users to visit their profile without editing their posts.

Here is my Profil view:

```
def Profil(request, username):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'blog/visitor.html')
    else:
        u = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user = request.user
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {'user': user, 'user_url':u,'posts': posts}
        return render(request, 'blog/profil.html', context)
```

And here my Index view

```
def IndexView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
       base_template_name = 'blog/base.html'
    else:
       base_template_name = 'blog/visitor.html'

    posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', 
                  {'posts':posts, 'base_template_name':base_template_name})
```

( Is there any other solution apart this ? )

My urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$',  views.Profil, name = 'profil'),
```

and a link from index.html to profil.html looks like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:profil' user.username %}">{{post.user.username }}</a>
```

the problem with this is when i click on the link it passes with the current user I'm logging in with and not the user that I click on it

LogIn with admin and want to see Ala's profile:

[image: Link from 'Ala' to his profil]

When I click it shows in the url this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/imedadmin/ which is supposed to be 'Ala' instead of 'imedadmin'.

Comment: You're using the username of the logged in user in the profile link here: `{% url 'blog:profil' user.username %}`. Replace `user` with the actual user whose profile you want to link.

Comment: What shoud I replace it with ?

Comment: Are you showing the name of the user in the link? Can you show the full `<a href="...">...</a>` code? Or show your index view.

Comment: Try this: `{% url 'blog:profil' post.user.username %}`

Comment: Didn't work :( it shows this error "Reverse for 'profil' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.."

Comment: `{{ post.user.username }}` shows the username of that user, right? If so, it should work. Can you double check all the spellings, make sure there's no typo?

Comment: It's good, but I think probably there is something missing within my Profile view, I just can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can send a variable to view in your render function, call it isHim. When logged in user is himself, set it equal to true and when it's not, set it to false. In you're view, check it with {{if isHim}} and then enable/disable edit buttons. I've used it and it answered.

Comment: Can you show in my code how to do it, pls I really need it ASAP

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

```
{% if request.user.id == post.user.id %}
 # ur code {% endif %}
```

in the templates dir.